# How to get current signal handler on iOS?

Tags: ios, c, signals

Hi i need to get current signal handler that was set with this method:

```
signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
```

How to do that?

Comment: This is more of a C question than an iOS question. You will probably get better help searching the C questions and/or tagging this with the C tag.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you i have added "c" tag to my question.

Comment: The only way I know is to change the signal handler:  `signal()` return the previous handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the C standard does not foresee reading the current value of the handler.

But fortunately [signal()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html) returns the previous value when you change the handler.  Hence with a slight risk you could do:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);  /* for convenience */

sighandler_t current_handler; 
current_handler = signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_IGN);  /* (1) */
signal (SIGSERV, current_handler); /* (2) */
```

There are two risks:

- There could be a (very unliklely) error causing `signal()` to return `SIG_ERR`.  You would then lose the current handler for good!  According to  iOS man page above, and based on the signal value you're interested in, the conditions for errors are not met.
- If a `SIGSEGV` would be raised between (1) and (2)  you would not intercept it.  However, looking at the two statements, they are unlikely to trigger a segmentation violation (SIGSEGV)